# IList with Points (X,Y) forming a circle. Trying to find top right/left, bottom left/right points

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have an IList that has points forming a circle.
I have retreived the min/max X and min/max Y from this IList with this:

```
float minX = pixelBrightList.Min(e => e.X);
float maxX = pixelBrightList.Max(e => e.X);
float minY = pixelBrightList.Min(e => e.Y);
float maxY = pixelBrightList.Max(e => e.Y);
```

This is, of course, the top, bottom, left and right positions for my circle.
I don't have the radian of the circle because it might not always be completely round. That is why I would like to collect more data before calculating the circle diameter.

**I would like to retreive the top left, top right, bottom left and bottom right points from this list.**

I'm kinda new to the programming so I might not have searched for the correct terms but I could only find examples for this. Would very much appreciate the help :)

[image]

Comment: If it's a circle, but it might not be round, then what *is* it?

Comment: I guess one way to do it is to identify the centre of the circle (or whatever it is), then draw a line which passes through the centre with a gradient of 1, and find the point which is closest to this line: that's the top-right point. Repeat for the others. However, if your circle is actually a rectangle with width 2 and height 1, this obviously won't work. Another way is to rotate the whole thing 45 degrees (again, you'll need the centre), then find the min/max x/y points again

Comment: what is the TopLeft point? a circle (and in general every polygon) has no point that is both the most high and the most left . consider a square with vertices at {1,,0)(1,1),(-1, 0), (-1,-1): what is the topLeft for this square? same apply for a circle with center in (0,0) and radius 1

Comment: @GianPaolo I'd argue that there are plenty of polygons with a top left point, the square with vertices (0,0)(1,0)(1,1)(0,1) would have a top left corner of (0,1) for example, but yes, a top left corner on a circle makes no sense, mostly due to (mathematically speaking) a circle not having any corners. (P.S your example square isn't even a square btw, it's not even a closed polygon)

Comment: If I had a completely round circle I would have no need for more points. It's a circle, but i might have a small dent or damage. If that dent or damage if placed upwards, bottom, left OR right it will then collect an incorrect point. I've updated the main question with an image to clarify.

Comment: you could try to find a circle of 'best fit' to the points, maybe minimising the distances from the points to a circle with some centre, which you may also have to determine - do you know what the centre of the 'circle' is?
Having found this notional circle, you will then know how much the total deviation is of all the points, which would be zero for a perfect circle.

Comment: I don't know the center of the circle unless I calculate it from the points I have collected. But if the points are incorrect the center would also be incorrect. Is there no way of finding the 45, 135, 225 and 315 degree points in the IList somehow?

Comment: How are you generating those "deformed circles"? What are you planning to do with the "hot corners" if you areble to identify them?

Comment: @MindSwipe ops, i wrote down a wrong square. The point in general is that given a set of points designing a polygon, it _can happen_ that there is a Top left point, but in general this is not true. what would the algorithm return in this case? and of course I agree, surely a circle has not a "top left" point, at least in the "natural" interpretation of TopLeft

Comment: Sorry if I got people hung up on the top left/right part. I want to extract the white pixel at 45° (what I call top right of the circle) from my list filled with Point(s). There is a camera that is generating this circles. If I have these points I can get a more accurate calculation of the diameter of the object (circle).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use something like [EmguCV](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) since this contain many methods specially designed to solve problems like this. You could start by checking out the [HoughCircles](https://HoughCircles) since this is designed to find circles in images. If you have points along the border you could also try the [FitEllipse](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Ellipse_Fitting_in_CSharp) method.

This should hopefully help you find a circle that follow the actual contour and ignores noise around the boarder.

You could also try writing a circle fitting method yourself, probably using some solver method from a library like [Math.net](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/), but it will help if you are familiar with the math. I'm not really knowledgeable enough to explain this.